# Is there a difference between $g(x,y)$ and $g(x;y)$?

Tags: notation

Is there a reason that the second notation uses a semicolon?

Here's the definition:

> we say $g(x;y)$ is a Green's function
>
> $$g(x;y) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        \sin(kx)\sin(k(y-1)/k\sin(k) & : x \lt y\\
>        \sin(ky)\sin(k(x-1)/k\sin(k) & : y \lt x\\    \end{array}
>    \right.$$

Comment: There is no difference, but the notation $g(x;y)$ suggests that we are going to think of $y$ as a parameter. For a fixed value of $y$, we will be interested in the function $x \mapsto g(x; y)$. It would have been ok to use the notation $g(x,y)$ instead, and some authors do this when discussing Green's functions.

Comment: @littleO it seems like you could make that comment verbatim into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post my comment here so that the question receives an answer:

There is no difference, but the notation $g(x;y)$ suggests that we are going to think of $y$ as a parameter. For a fixed value of $y$, we will be interested in the function $x \mapsto g(x;y)$. It would have been ok to use the notation $g(x,y)$ instead, and some authors do this when discussing Green's functions.